# Image with border not being created

Tags: php

I am trying to resize an image by adding a border but it won't save. Any idea what is wrong? I am doing this to resize the image

```
 $add = ($manFolderRoot."/".$firstImage);
    $im1=ImageCreateFromJpeg($add);

    $width=ImageSx($im1);

    $height=ImageSy($im1);

  

    $borderW = $lW-$width;
    $borderH = $lH-$height;

    $img_adj_width=$width+(2*$borderW);

    $img_adj_height=$height+(2*$borderH);

    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($img_adj_width,$img_adj_height);

    $border_color = imagecolorallocate($newimage, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefilledrectangle($newimage,0,0,$img_adj_width,$img_adj_height,$border_color);

    imageCopyResized($newimage,$im1,$borderW,$borderH,0,0,$width,$height,$width,$height);

  
    imagejpeg($newimage,$save,100); // change here to $add2 if a new image is to be created

    chmod("$add",0666);
```

Comment: What is `$save` supposed to contain?

Comment: Where are `$lW` and `$lH` defined?